# MongoDB - readWriteAnyDatabase role not working

Tags: mongodb

I have a user with a `readWriteAnyDatabase` role but still it cannot list the collections in a db I have named `ops`.

I have another user with a `root` role and he succeed to list the collections.

What can be the cause?

The error I am getting: `Not authorized to execute command: listCollections...`

using mongodb: 3.4.7

I have 2 dbs:

- admin
- ops

I try to view the collections in `ops`

Answer (score 0):

Can you login to the mongo shell as admin and run `db.getUser("xxx")` (where xxx is the username in question) and show the output.

Also, can you verify that you are in fact authenticating as this user in question. How are you testing this via the mongo shell?

Another test, login to the mongo shell as admin, then run `db.auth("xxx", "passwordForXXX")`.